# How do I determine what is calling an Azure function?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure SQL Server DB. It is being kept alive by some queries being run ie it never sleeps. I can see in Query Performance Insight that these queries are run 8 times per hour (occasionally 10 and once 6 per hour). Now some of these were called by Azure functions which were timer activated and have been successfully switched off. However, there are HTTP request functions still being fired and running queries and I want to work out why.

Are there any ways to determine what is firing these?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring)? Application Insights should show the communication

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Dependency Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies)  with Application Insights.

For Azure Functions,

> Azure Functions requires separate settings to enable SQL text
> collection: within host.json set "EnableDependencyTracking": true, and
> "DependencyTrackingOptions": { "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation":
> true } in applicationInsights.

Answer (score 0):

for a quick win and if you have access to Azure Functions Stack
you can [Enable Application Insights integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration) , it will setup relevant settings(e.g APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY) on your runtime environment/settings , and use Dependency tracking and Application Map to see where are the calls.